# Express error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: node.js, express

Posting here is infrequent. I apologize if my post is missing something.

This is my first API with Express and node.js. The code below is producing the following...SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tried moving the colon white space and replacing colon with equal sign but apparently those are not resolutions to this issue.

Simplified the app.get() method to produce a string output on the browser page and that works perfectly. However, when I try to actually do anything meaningful outside of sending a string to the browser I am getting this error back from express which causes the app to crash. Using sublime text editor and it shows red highlights on the closing pairs of bracket and parenthesis. Any help?

```
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()

app.get('/fitaid', (req,res) => { 

    axios.get('https://www.lifeaidbevco.com/apparel') 
      .then((response : AxiosResponse<any>) => {
        const html = response.data
        console.log(html)
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what *exactly* is unclear about the error message you’ve provided? A colon `:` character doesn’t belong in your parameter definition where you seem to think it does. This is a TypeScript-specific convention, but Node’s interpreter is not capable of running uncompiled TypeScript source code. Can you provide a source for your implicit claim to the contrary?

Comment: TLDR looks like you're trying to run typescript in node. You need to convert it to JavaScript first.

Comment: If you're not purposely using TypeScript and want this to run as plain Javascript, then change this `.then((response : AxiosResponse<any>) => {` to this `.then((response) => {`

Comment: @esqew Thank you for your response. I can see that a colon does not belong there. Hopefully, readers can see I clearly don't know how to resolve the issue lol. To clarify...Do you know how to resolve the issue to get the code to work? :-)

Comment: @Phix Thank you that is a huge nudge in a direction that provides a possible resolution. Thank you for a response that attempts to resolve the issue! You rock!

Comment: @jfriend00 Your ability to assess the issue is pretty much spot on. I did not realize I was using TypeScript like esqew mentioned. You however explicitly made a clear effort towards resolving the issue with your sample code. I will try this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, this looks like an error caused by the TypeScript syntax you're using so I'm guessing that you either didn't intend to use TypeScript syntax and you need to convert to plain Javascript syntax or for some reason, you aren't compiling your TypeScript into Javascript before running it.

If you intend to just write and run plain Javascript, then remove the type information in the callback declaration and change this:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()

app.get('/fitaid', (req,res) => { 

    axios.get('https://www.lifeaidbevco.com/apparel') 
      .then((response : AxiosResponse<any>) => {
        const html = response.data
        console.log(html)
    })
})
```

to this:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const app = express()

app.get('/fitaid', (req,res) => { 

    axios.get('https://www.lifeaidbevco.com/apparel').then((response) => {
        const html = response.data;
        console.log(html);
        res.send(html);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```

Also, note that you must send a response of some type in your request handler. Currently, you just show outputting to the console with no response being sent.

And, you should be catch any errors from your `axios()` call and sending an error response.

Comment: This code was the fix for me! I cannot thank you enough. I spent about 3 hours trying to remedy the situation but your answer fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

try with the below code, it will be simpler and easier to understand your code

```
app.get('/fitaid', async (req,res) => {
    const response = await axios.get('https://www.lifeaidbevco.com/apparel');
    console.log(response.data.html);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow! Very thorough response and potential resolution to my issue! Grateful for your time. Stackoverflow needs more users like those who post thorough resolutions. I will try this as well.

Comment: @TranTrung Thank you for your response! I tried your code fix but unfortunately I received an undefined response on the server.

Comment: @mrmillmill hi there.
which one is undefined. response? data? html?